# Convert MS Word Wildcards search patterns to Regex?

Tags: regex, ms-word

I am trying to convert a MS Word search wildcard pattern to regular expression (which can be used at http://regexr.com), since Word stated my pattern is too complex for it to handle.

My search wildcard is look like this:

```
A[!A]{1,}A[!A]{1,}A[!A]{1,}A[!A]{1,}A[!A]{1,}A[!A]{1,}A[!A]{1,}
```

Which will match those string patterns in MS Word:

```
A [a string which does not contain character "A"] A [a string which does not contain character "A"] A [...]
```

But I cannot find any possible solution to convert it into regular expression which I could use on that website.

I already researched in several topics about some kinds of converting (negative lookahead/lookbehind), but it seems that it would not match my problem.

I am very appreciated if you guys can share some idea! Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't it be enough to replace `[!A]` with `[^A]`

Comment: @SebastianProske is on point, and here is a [live regex](https://regex101.com/r/yG5fS1/1) where you can see it in action.

Comment: Thank you guys, but the solution won't work. I've tried it before but [^A] just look for a single character, not a string of text.

The expression A[!A]{1,}A means that at least (but it is not limited to) 1 occurrences of "non-A" character will happen between two A characters.

Those are examples I derived from MS Word search result: A0BBA, A0B, ABA, A00BA.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `!` by `^` and optionnaly `{1,}` by `+`.

```
A[^A]+A[^A]+A[^A]+A[^A]+A[^A]+A[^A]+A[^A]+
```

See this nice [regexp cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, but the expression just won't work for me. I've tried but it only just recognized [^A] as a single character, not a string. Also, whether we add "+" or not, the result is still the same.

Comment: Depending on the tool you're using, you might need to escape the `+` or `{` or `}` with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that the answer is `A[^A]+A` for every `A [a string which does not contain character "A"] A`

Thank you guys! :D